# Populate Active Directory with SSIS

Tags: ssis, active-directory

I've seen loads of posts to pull data FROM AD but I need to update AD and can't find what I'm looking for. My company has been using a third party vendor (intelli-desk) to house dept., manager, and phone etx. information for many years. AD was just used to create usernames and assign domain access. We know have a need to update AD with the information from within intelli-desk to AD. I have a query already built that compares AD and the intelli-desk db and would like to take the results of that query where sn and givenName match and update Ext., Dept., etc. in AD. I was thinking an SSIS package might be the best way to do this so that it can be a scheduled job because I don't think we are going to stop using the 3rd party software. Does anyone have any suggestions on using SSIS to this and if so how might you go about it. If not what else could be used?

Comment: There might be 3rd party components, I'd check CozyRoc first, otherwise you're looking at .NET script as a destination. The methods you'll be interested in are in the `System.DirectoryServices` library. That said, the account that can perform this feat will have godlike powers in your environment so be cautious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just recently had to complete a similar task *(insert,update)* Active Directory users from database. There're few options you can accomplish this task:

1. Use 3rd party softwares like @billinkc mentioned in his comment. However, there're more cons to this than pros. Most of them are not cost efficient and moreover, they are limited on what you can do *(if you don't buy source code).* Wouldn't recommend taking this route.
2. There's a way to accomplish this task using `SSIS` package. This technet [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1293.processing-active-directory-information-in-ssis.aspx) explains on how to import users to Active Directory using external source. `SSIS` package will use external script written either in `VBA` or `C#`. The `C#` example provided in the article is written in older `.NET` library. It's using `DirectoryEntry` class. There's nothing wrong with using this class, however, with `.NET 3.5` and higher, Microsoft introduced `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, which is much simpler to use.
3. Write it yourself using `AccountManagement` namespace. It's not hard as it sounds.

Since you have all users information in database, you can write a `stored procedure` that will return user(s) information.

Here's something for you to start with.

Load user information from database by calling `stored procedure`.

```
 public static DataTable GetUserInfoByUsername(string username)
 {
     //call stor proc to return data
     //return datatable or custom class that will hold user iformation
 }
```

Write two methods that will `Create` and `Update` a user. Use values from `datatable` to populate user properties in Active Directory.

```
public static string CreateUser(DataTable dt, string password)
{
   //CREATE CONNECTION TO ACTIVE DIRECTORY
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
   {
       //CREATE A NEW USERPRINCIPAL OBJECT
       using (UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
       {
          //TODO: you need to populate the below info with values from dt
          principal.Enabled = true; //IF NOT ENABLED YOU CAN'T AUTHENTICATE THE USER
          principal.UserPrincipalName = username;
          principal.Name = "name";
          principal.DisplayName = "firstname lastname";
          principal.EmailAddress = "email@test.com";
          principal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "12345678910";
          principal.GivenName = "firstname";
          principal.Surname = "lastname";
          principal.SetPassword(password);
          try
          {
             principal.Save();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)           
          {
             throw;
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

You can take a similar approach to update users.

```
public static void UpdateUser(string userName, DataTable dt)
{
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
    {
        //you have more than one way to search for a user in AD. Identitype has more choises
        using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Identitype.samAccountName, username))
        {
            if (principal !== null)
            //update user properties with data from datatable dt
            ...
            principal.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Something to remember. By default `UserPrincipal` class doesn't display every active directory property. The quickest way to get to those properties is to use `DirectoryEntry` class. You can call `GetUnderlyingObject()` method of `principal`.

```
DirectoryEntry de = (principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

if (de != null)
{
   if (de.Properties.Contains("company"))
   string company = de.Properties["company"][0].ToString();
}
```

If you want to run some kind of job to perform these operations just have your `stored procedure` to return all users and use `foreach` loop before calling any of those methods.

I suggest you write a windows service and do all these operations there.

***NOTE** the code is not complete. Based on your needs you need to modify the code.**

Comment: Thanks @Burzum! This is the direction i wanted to head down. I'll work with this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @PistolPete, glad I could help.